# How to find the first empty row in Excel when subsequent rows are not empty

Tags: excel, vba

How do I find the first completely empty row on a particular worksheet looking top down?

Because the sheet includes a Totals row at the end of several empty rows, I don't think I can simply use the `Range.End` property and offset by 1.

Comment: Sure did, @ARich. Also searched Stackoverflow's database and the MSDN site. I have been unable to find a solution to the specific problem I described above, which is why I posted the question. Please try to keep this site civil. Thanks.

Comment: My comment wasn't an attack. :) A quick search returned many examples of how to do this. [Here's a SO example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875115/excel-vba-go-to-first-blank-row). The last answer uses the method I referred to before. Just be sure to include the `.Find` argument `SearchDirection:=xlNext`.

Comment: what code have you already been wrestling with to solve this problem? You should show an attempt?

Comment: @ken, see section "Find Last Row in a Sheet" in [this SiddharthRout's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920)

Comment: @simico it's actually find the first entirely blank row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the first blank row, loop through the actual `UsedRange` determined by `Find` using `CountA` to test for a blank row

If no row is found, use the next row after the end of the last cell determined by the `Find`

```
   Sub Method2()
   Dim rng1 As Range
   Dim rng2 As Range

   Dim bFound As Boolean

   Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", [a1], xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)

   For Each rng1 In Range([a1], Cells(rng2.row, "A"))
   If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(rng1.row)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox rng1.row & " is the first blank row"
        bFound = True
        Exit For
   End If
   Next rng1

   If Not bFound Then MsgBox rng2.Offset(1, 0).row & " is the first blank row"

   End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, @brettdj. It was my understanding that UsedRange will also include cells that are now empty but at one time may have included a value. Is there a way to tweak this so that the first currently empty row is selected even if that row at one time contained values?

Comment: @Ken, thats why I have a `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` to force a recalc :)

Comment: @ken but made it bulletproof with a `Find`

Answer (score 0):

forgive me if I've misinterpreted the question.

Totals is always the last row and you'd therefore like to find the next row.
I assume that Totals changes the row it is located on and there are blank rows in front of it.

Why does the location of Totals change?

I'd just make cell where totals is located a named range "Totals":

[image]

Then if some extra rows are inserted I can still get to the Totals row ok:

[image]

So in `VBA` its then trivial:

```
Sub Method2()

    MsgBox "Total named range is  " & ActiveSheet.Range("Totals").Address(0, 0)
    MsgBox "Next empty row is  " & ActiveSheet.Range("Totals").Row + 1

End Sub
```

Comment: my apologies--I don't think my question was clear enough. I'm attempting to locate the first instance of an empty row in the spreadsheet. In your example above, it would be row 1.

Comment: @ken a full blank row, or blank in a certain column(s)?